# ASP.Net doesn't know textbox

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, textbox

I've created a form in asp.net where the user inserts email address subject and a message and then he clicks on send.

The mail is being send with some fake inputs

I'm trying to get the input from the textbox but for some reason I can't.

This is what I did in my asp site:

```
<form id="contact-form"  >
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Name" CssClass="labelnew"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Enter name"  required="required"></asp:TextBox>

                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Your Email Address" CssClass="labelnew"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtemail" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Enter email" required="required"></asp:TextBox>

                    </div>

                          <div class="form-group">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblmsg" runat="server" Text="Message" CssClass="labelnew"></asp:Label>
                              <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" placeholder="Message" CssClass="form-control"  TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="9" Columns="25" required="required"></asp:TextBox>
                           </div>


                    <div class="col-md-12">

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Send Message"  onclick="Button1_Click" 
                            BackColor="#0066CC" Font-Names="Aharoni" ForeColor="White" 
                            ></asp:Button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </form>
```

This is what I did in my c# code behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
mailMessage.To.Add("mymail@ebay.com");
mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("a"); 
mailMessage.Subject = "ya";
mailMessage.Body = "ya";
    SmtpClient smtpcl = new SmtpClient("mysmtp");
smtpcl.Send(mailMessage);
   string a= TextBox1.text;
 }
```

For some reason it doesn't seem to know TextBox1, any idea why?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: I'm nearly sure there should be "runat=server" for "form" too.

Comment: hi thanks for helping, yes, the error message is : "Error 58 The name 'TextBox1' does not exist in the current context".

Comment: i tried to insert the runat="Server" in the form and it didn't work

Comment: Maybe this can help http://forums.asp.net/t/1149621.aspx?The+name+TextBox1+does+not+exist+in+the+current+context+in+button+click+handler

Comment: Remove the TextBox1 and then add it back.

Comment: Sometimes I had to save the aspx file and reopened it, after that it was fine.

Comment: As per @TimurMannapov's comment - have you set the `form` to `runat='server'`?

Comment: Please remove the spurious [tag:asp-classic] tag. (That's "spurious" as in "this question has nothing to do with asp-classic"; not trying to imply that the asp-classic tag shouldn't exist or anything like that.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than the runat="server" in  tag.. please check the following...
1.  AutoEventWireup="true".  If not set not true, you need to explicitly do it in the code behind.

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeBehind="YourPageName.aspx.vb" Inherits="YourNamespace.YourPageName" %>
```

2. is it partial class?

   Partial Class YourPageName Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

   End Class

Comment: perfect the AutoEventWireup="false" solved the issue
thanks a lot guys for helping